# Facing issue to start server

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg

I am learning React from an online resource and on a daily basis I push and pull code. Today when I try to run the project `yarn start` I am getting this issue

```
yarn run v1.22.5
error Couldn't find a package.json file in "/home/aniket/Desktop/react_applications/practice_react_app"
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

When I googled I got few answers such as to run yarn clean cache
Also, I tried to delete the project and take a fresh clone of the project but still it shows me the same error

My github repository URL: https://github.com/aniketstiwari/practice_react_app

Comment: Did you read the error message? It makes it pretty clear what the problem is.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes I have already read the error message. And the file package.json is alreadyinside my project

Comment: There's no package file in the root of that repo (although confusingly there's both a lock file and a dependency directory, presumably from when you've *previously* tried to run Yarn in the wrong directory). You should probably make the practice-react directory the root of the repo.

Comment: package.json file is available in the root of the repo

Comment: We can see that, for the repo you linked to at least, that's not true.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Correct me if I am wrong https://github.com/aniketstiwari/practice_react_app/blob/main/practice-react/package.json     this is the package.json inside my project

Comment: And that's *not* in the root of the repo, *not* in the directory you're trying to run the Yarn command in. As you can clearly see in the link and on the page, it's in `./react-practice/`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have fixed it by adding node_modules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution by adding the node_modules inside the project and then run the command yarn.

Comment: What do you mean *"adding the node_modules"*? Installing the dependencies? The problem is that you were in the wrong directory, there wasn't a package file present, so it's unclear how this could possibly be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

There's no `package.json` file on the path `home/aniket/Desktop/react_applications/practice_react_app`

Try

```
cd practice-react
```

Then

```
yarn start
```